# HTML table in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a code like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/nf0z3pk3/

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body style="height:100%;">
<div style="height:100%;" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="next"> 
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"> 
<table border=1 style="width:100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:5%" id="activitiesByMonthTable" class="">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Count</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr id="row" class="reportRow">
    <td>March</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row" class="reportRow">
    <td>April</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>    
   </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="item"> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae egestas purus. </p>
      <p><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer to jsfiddle link. Now, it works well with one problem. When you click next or previous button it slides to the other div. When you try to come back to the first slide, it comes back to the table but it does not come back to the table sliding. It just looks like it reloads a page. First the table is invisible, then it is visible back. I think it recreates the table. Any help is appreciated.